# Efficient Strategies for Loading Complex Models in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm seeking expertise on efficiently managing the loading of large, complex models within Autodesk Viewer. Our application involves displaying various models and detailed information of a mechanical structure, which are inherently complex.

We often encounter issues where the browser crashes or experiences prolonged loading times, especially when handling these large, intricate files. This problem is more pronounced on mobile devices, likely due to memory limitations.

Our current strategy has been to divide our model into smaller sections, but we've found that managing a large number of these smaller models also presents challenges in terms of loading times and browser stability.

Additionally, we are exploring the capabilities of SVF2. Are there any new possibilities or advantages with SVF2 that could help in our situation?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, experiences, or solutions from anyone adept at handling large or numerous models in Autodesk Viewer. Tips, suggestions, or best practices to enhance efficiency and stability in such scenarios are highly welcome.

We use the 3D modeling feature and not the drawing part of the Viewer.

Comment: Could you please send us additional details on your implementation and the challenges you're facing through aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com?

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches you could take to optimize the performance and experience:

1. Use [selective loading](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-feature-selective-loading), so only what's necessary gets rendered.
2. [Skip properties db](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only) if you don't need them (refer [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/mimicking-viewer-fit-view-without-properties-database) if you need selection or fit to view without properties db)
3. Use [SVF2](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready) to optimize geometry (just know that it won't optimize geometry across Viewer instances)